# How to get key values which locate in different level of a nest json?

Tags: python, json

Firstly, here is the snippet of the json:

```json
{
    "messages":
    [
        {
            "id": 460,
            "type": "message",
            "date": "2022-01-01T15:10:19",
            "text": "hello, ",
        },
        {
            "id": 461,
            "type": "message",
            "date": "2022-01-01T15:10:19",
            "text":
            [
                "this ",
                {
                    "type": "bold",
                    "text": "is"
                },
                " the ",
                {
                    "type": "underline",
                    "text": "code"
                },
                " names."
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 462,
            "type": "message",
            "date": "2022-01-01T15:43:41",
            "text":
            [
                "But, ",
                {
                    "type": "bold",
                    "text": "list, set and string "
                },
                " are already builtin functions, so using these names is not recommended."
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to use **Python** to get all value of the "text" key, which locate in different level of the json, so I can merge them to a sentence as below:

> Hello, this is the code names. but list, set and string are already builtin functions, so using these names is not recommended.

I've tried a bit with native dict manipulations and also tried the module Jmespath for json in Python, but I still can't workout a way to get it done. So you may know I am a newbie of Python, hope I can have a easy understand solution to achieve my goal here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may handle the different datatype you can find `dict,list,str` and apply the good logic

- `dict` : if value is a container : search in it
- `list` : search in all element of it
- `str` : add it

```py
def search(data, search_key) -> str:
    r = ''
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for key, value in data.items():
            if isinstance(value, (dict, list)):
                r += search(value, search_key)
            if isinstance(value, str) and key == search_key:
                r += value

    if isinstance(data, list):
        for item in data:
            r += search(item, search_key)

    if isinstance(data, str):
        r += data

    return r
```

```py
v = {"messages": [
    {"id": 460, "type": "message", "date": "2022-01-01T15:10:19", "text": "hello, "},
    {"id": 461, "type": "message", "date": "2022-01-01T15:10:19",
     "text": ["this ", {"type": "bold", "text": "is"}, " the ",
              {"type": "underline", "text": "code"}, " names."]},
    {"id": 462, "type": "message", "date": "2022-01-01T15:43:41",
     "text": ["But, ", {"type": "bold", "text": "list, set and string "},
              " are already builtin functions, so using these names is not recommended."]}
]}

result = search(v, 'text')
print(result)
# hello, this is the code names.But, list, set and string  are already builtin functions, so using these names is not recommended.
```

Comment: Thank you very much, works and neat! plus well explained. I didn't know function can call itself within

Comment: @user3127293 that is called "recursive"